# Open source tool to view DTED and DEM raster-data

Tags: open-source-gis, dem, dted

I am new to GIS field. Is there any open source GIS tool to view DTED and DEM tiff-files?

**Update 1**

I have some DTED files and DEM files. I want to open and see those files using some open source GIS tools. Can I use MapWindow GIS or QGIS for this? Are there any other tools available?

Please advise.

Comment: What file extention (format) do those data have? DTED/DEM could be anything from a tiff/png/etc to a database.

Answer (score 2):

in qgis, you can see your dted files as contour map or hillshade map, if it helps.

for converting your file to contour:

```
Raster → Extraction → Contour
```

for converting it to hillshade:

```
Raster → Analysis → DEM (Terrain Models).
```

This examples from [Paulina Fernandez Luengo](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jef243/homepage%20files/GEOG486/Lesson6/GEOG486_Lesson6.htm) which shows hillshade and contour map together.

[image: cnhl]

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 2):

QGIS supports tiff and DTED files. You can load them by going to **Layer → Add Raster Layer** and then navigating to your files. Here's a tutorial on [working with terrain data in QGIS](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/03/working-with-terrain-data-in-qgis.html) that should get you started.

Good luck :)

Comment: You can easily drag and drop files in QGIS. If it is not supported, an error apears.

Answer (score 1):

GRASS GIS supports about 80 raster formats including various DEM and DTED formats. You can do it all via a convenient wizard:

http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Location_Wizard#Import_raster_data

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [SAGA GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org/). It comes in different flavours (.exe or portable, 32 or 64 bits, Windows or Linux), and it is a handy tool.
You can import DTED files, and also .tiff files using Import/Export - GDAL/OGR > GDAL: Import Raster module.

[image: Import a .dt1 file]

After that you can make 2D and 3D visualizations, coutour extraction, shading and so on.

[image: 2D view]

[image: 3D view]